# MAUI Shell: using same page class with different parameters

Tags: .net, maui

I have same page class that displays different information. In MAUI example, instead of *DogsPage*, *CatsPage*, *ElephantsPage*, etc, I'm will be using just *AnimalPage* with different navigation parameters.

How to organize routing in this case, when same Page class is used? **One important thing**: so it could be used in bottom bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use constructor. Navigation has built in query parameters.
You can always:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(MyAnimalPage)}", params);
```

Where params is:

```
Dictionary<string, object>
```

In your AnimalPage ViewModel, you implement the interface IQueryAttributable.
And handle the parameters like that:

```
public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> params)
```

This is one way to avoid using the word "new", and pass parameters in the constructor.
A good place to start reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation

Edit: For the dark magic you want to use, there are different ways.

Shell.Current.CurrentItem holds the Route. You can use it, lets say in OnNavigatedTo, to determine what route has been used.

Alternatively, OnNavigating of your AppShell can be used to determine where you are navigating to.

I do not use this in real project however. If you have, say DetailsPage, it makes much sense to have parameter, of the Model you want to see the details, but it is not the best idea, to be able to pass different models.

Comment: The thing is how to define it in the toolbar. I want AnimalPage("dog") and AnimalPage("cat") in bottom bar.
I think I should specify this in the quesion to avoid confusion.

Comment: I've edited my answer with two ways you how you can do such things, it is not the only way, there are other options. It will be working, you can even integrate this with your MVVM, the big question here is - is this worth it? You want two different routes navigating to the same page. Why not make those buttons part of the page itself?

Comment: In my project there are user-defined lists, so half of pages are some "GeneralPage" that take different data from server. Simply put, I don't know beforehand if it will be "cats", "dogs", or even "apples" and "planets". And user also could place some of the pages on bottom bar or flyout menu. Even with intercepting OnNavigatedTo I still couldn't figure out how to place buttons in bottom bar in that case.

Comment: You can lookup how to make TabBars.  (It will be radio buttons with BindableLayout in most cases). You will have some difficulty making the first one, after that you will be able to customize them and they are extremely flexible. Check this out: https://dev.to/davidortinau/making-a-tabbar-or-segmentedcontrol-in-net-maui-54ha

Comment: If the answer is "it is impossible with standard methods", it is answer nevertheless, no matter how sad it is. I have hand-made toolbar already, but wanted to move to something basic and built-in.